# Elimination and the Intersection of Two Hyperplanes

Tags: linear-algebra

Say I am given two $2$-dimensional planes in $3$-space: $2x + 5y + z = 7$ and $5x - 2y - z = 3$. Now using elimination I get the $2$-dimensional plane $7x +3y = 10$. But in $2$-space, the equation
$7x +3y = 10$ would be a $1$-dimensional line. Does that mean that the intersection of the two original $2$-dimensional planes is a $1$-dimensional line? And is the equation of that line in
$2$-space
$7x + 3y = 10$?

Am I even asking a sensible question?